# Python selenium print page problem with page layout

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, pdf, printing

I have encountered a problem with python selenium while I was trying to print (save as pdf) a bunch of pages from an essay with a python program that I wrote and the selenium plugin for it. The problem is that the content of some pages does not fit on one A4 page, and the automatic "page-breaking" cuts the pages in a very silly way. As you can see in the attached image of the pdf, the bottom row of the first page is cut in half (therefore cannot be read) and the top 3-4 row of the next page's content is also missing (due to the margin on the top of the page, i guess?). I would like to implement a solution in my code, so the "page-breaking" is done correctly (every row shows).
The pdf is not in English, but I think it is irrelevant regarding the problem.

The parts regarding the settings of the print in my code:
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

```
settings = {
       "recentDestinations": [{
            "id": "Save as PDF",
            "origin": "local",
            "account": "",
        }],
        "selectedDestinationId": "Save as PDF",
        "version": 2,
        "isHeaderFooterEnabled": False
    }
prefs = {'printing.print_preview_sticky_settings.appState': json.dumps(settings)}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
chrome_options.add_argument('--kiosk-printing')
CHROMEDRIVER_PATH = '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

And i call the print like this:

```
browser.execute_script('window.print();')
```

A possible solution would be a larger page size, but I need A4 size because I would like to print it at home.

[an occurrence of the bug here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlGn0.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Selenium and ChromeDriver, automatically scale the size of the page on print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58943350/using-selenium-and-chromedriver-automatically-scale-the-size-of-the-page-on-pri)

Comment: Try setting the page scale fit to page

Comment: I have tried setting the page to scale fit. The automatic scale-size would work, but if I scale the text to fit on one page, it is so small, that I cannot use it if I print the PDF (and that would be the purpose...).

If fact I have noticed that the error occures on the manual page-printing view, both in chromium browsers, and non-chromium browsers so it is not selenium that messes up the thing. However, I would need to resolve the problem in order to use my program.