# Enable backgroundCSS option when Saving PDFs of webpages with Selenium

Tags: python, css, selenium, pdf, chromium

I'm trying to "Print as PDF" a set of webpage reports repeatedly with a Selenium ChromeDriver script in Python.  As you can see below, if we have the "Background graphics" option selected, the header of the report renders perfectly. [image]

However, when I run Selenium, I cannot figure out how to set the parameter for background graphics. The saved PDF will instead look like this: [image]

Here is a minimally reproducible script that I've been attempting to run:

```html
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
import json
from time import sleep
import os

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
settings = {
    "recentDestinations": [{
            "id": "Save as PDF",
            "origin": "local",
            "account": "",
        }],
    "selectedDestinationId": "Save as PDF",
    "version": 2,
    #"cssBackground": 2,
    }

prefs = {'printing.print_preview_sticky_settings.appState': json.dumps(settings), }
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
chrome_options.add_argument('--kiosk-printing')
CHROMEDRIVER_PATH = '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, executable_path=CHROMEDRIVER_PATH)

driver.get("https://dash.gallery/dash-multipage-report/")
sleep(3)
driver.execute_script('window.print();')
sleep(5)
driver.quit()
```

I've done some digging on Chromium's documentation and I believe that I've found the cssBackground setting [here](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/eadef3f685cd9e96e94fcb9645b6838b6d0907a8/chrome/browser/resources/print_preview/data/model.js).  Additionally, there's a `BackgroundGraphicsModeRestriction` in [this file](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/eadef3f685cd9e96e94fcb9645b6838b6d0907a8/chrome/browser/resources/print_preview/print_preview.js) that might be affecting things?  I found what I thought would be a useful lead to setting the value [in this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58943350/using-selenium-and-chromedriver-automatically-scale-the-size-of-the-page-on-pri) but I can't seem to put the pieces together and check that "Background graphics" box from the start.  Any help that you can provide would be incredibly appreciated as I'm pretty stuck here.  I've also tried rendering my page's CSS with `-webkit-print-color-adjust:exact;` but it doesn't seem to capture the entire background.

Answer (score 0):

OP has probably moved on, but this was the first option when I googled, so just in case anyone else is looking for this, using the links above and a little further digging, I found this:
https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/eadef3f685cd9e96e94fcb9645b6838b6d0907a8/chrome/browser/resources/print_preview/data/model.js

There's a bunch of settings there, including `cssBackground`. For each setting, there's a key. For `cssBackground`, it's `isCssBackgroundEnabled`.

```
cssBackground: {
        value: false,
        unavailableValue: false,
        valid: true,
        available: true,
        setByPolicy: false,
        setFromUi: false,
        key: 'isCssBackgroundEnabled',
        updatesPreview: true,
      },
```

I set this to True, and it worked for me.

```
settings = {
"recentDestinations": [{
        "id": "Save as PDF",
        "origin": "local",
        "account": "",
    }],
"selectedDestinationId": "Save as PDF",
"isCssBackgroundEnabled": True,
"version": 2,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The default for headless printing should be background ON (i.e. i would not attempt to switch it off) but that could be that I always have it generally on though for this test had switched it off in a prior run and I kept my browser open just in case OFF would be respected?.

[image]

So using Edge (as its part of Windows Renting), I ran with a generous 6 seconds delay, to write the HTML as run time HTML2PDF regeneration:-

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --headless --print-to-pdf="C:\mydata\report.pdf" --virtual-time-budget=6000 https://dash.gallery/dash-multipage-report  
Report.pdf
```

Naturally if Edge was default PDF handler it would have popped up there in a new tab, so that second line could have been.

```
Timeout 6 & "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" "C:\mydata\report.pdf"
```